# How to use purrr:map() to read sheets from multiple excel files?

Tags: r, purrr

I have a tibble with a column for file paths and a column for the name of the sheets (paths removed for security):

```
x <- structure(list(file = c("2003_2005_DataDictionary.xlsx", "2003_2005_DataDictionary.xlsx", 
"2003_2005_DataDictionary.xlsx", "2003_2005_DataDictionary.xlsx", 
"2003_2005_DataDictionary.xlsx", "2003_2005_DataDictionary.xlsx", 
"1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx", "1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx", 
"1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx", "1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx", 
"1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx", "1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx", 
"1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx", "1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx", 
"1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx", "1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx", 
"1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx", "1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx", 
"1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx", "1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx"
), sheet = c("vartable05", "vartable04", "vartable03", "valuesets05", 
"valuesets04", "valuesets03", "vartable02", "vartable01", "vartable00", 
"vartable99", "vartable98", "vartable97", "vartable96", "valuesets02", 
"valuesets01", "valuesets00", "valuesets99", "valuesets98", "valuesets97", 
"valuesets96")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))

> x
# A tibble: 20 x 2
   file                          sheet      
   <chr>                         <chr>      
 1 2003_2005_DataDictionary.xlsx vartable05 
 2 2003_2005_DataDictionary.xlsx vartable04 
 3 2003_2005_DataDictionary.xlsx vartable03 
 4 2003_2005_DataDictionary.xlsx valuesets05
 5 2003_2005_DataDictionary.xlsx valuesets04
 6 2003_2005_DataDictionary.xlsx valuesets03
 7 1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx vartable02 
 8 1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx vartable01 
 9 1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx vartable00 
10 1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx vartable99 
11 1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx vartable98 
12 1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx vartable97 
13 1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx vartable96 
14 1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx valuesets02
15 1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx valuesets01
16 1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx valuesets00
17 1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx valuesets99
18 1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx valuesets98
19 1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx valuesets97
20 1996_2002_DataDictionary.xlsx valuesets96
```

I need to read each sheet using `read_excel()` and combine to a single data frame, however the following code doesn't work:

````
x %>% 
   map_dfr(~read_excel(path = .$file, sheet = .$sheet))
#Error in .$file : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried imap as well with no luck.
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can either use `map2` for corresponding elements of each column

```
library(purrr)
map2(x$file, x$sheet, ~ read_excel(path = .x, sheet = .y)
```

Or with `pmap`

```
pmap(x, ~ read_excel(path = ..1, sheet = ..2))
```

Or if we rename the columns,

```
x %>%
   rename(path = file) %>%
   pmap(read_excel)
```

Comment: Interesting.  So this works as you suggested, but if I do: x %>% map2(.$file, .$sheet, ~read_excel(path = .x, sheet = .y) I get "Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
* `.x` has length 2
* `.y` has length 10"

Comment: @jzadra You need `{}` to block it i.e. `x %>%{ map2(.$file, .$sheet, ~ .x)}`